# How to restrict floating point number in java

Tags: java, math

I've a floating point number 29.887628583132877%.. and I've to restrict the values to 29.88.. how to do this in java

Comment: you can´t, you´d need to use another class if you´d want to have the exact number.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to *format* your float, that is build a string representation with a specific precision in order to display it ? In such a case the linked QA won't help you much but you can just google "java format double".

Comment: Do you want to round the number or control how it is converted to a String?

Comment: The question has been closed, but try this: `num -= num % precision`. Precision is the least count that you want to store. The precision can be any number, including a floating point number. In your example, precision  will be `0.01`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
float num = 29.88344323323f;
System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", num));
```

And the result is:

```
29.88
```

Comment: can we do it for double using the same?

Comment: Yes no problem, you can do with both of them.